# Swap Nodes in Pairs recursively in Python

Tags: python

I'm sloving the leetcode 24 Swap Nodes in Pairs recursively. There is my code:

```py
class Solution:
    def swapPairs(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        if head == None or head.next == None:
            return head
        while head and head.next:
            p1,p2 = head, head.next
            p1.next = self.swapPairs(p2.next)
            p2.next = p1
        return p2
```

The answer to a N1->N2->N3->N4 should be N2->N1->N4->N3. But this code produce only N3->N1. I don't know why.

Comment: Why the `while` loop? I'd think you just have two swap the first two elements and append the swapped rest, which is what one iteration of the loop does.

Comment: add a exit condition from while loop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not test it, but the problem seems to be the `while` loop. Let's see what the code does:

- `swapPairs(N1->N2->N3->N4)`

  - `head` is `N1` and *stays* `N1` until the end
  - first iteration: `p1, p2 = N1, N2`

    - swapped to `N2->N1->swapPairs(N3->N4)`
    - `swapPairs(N3->N4)` again goes in the `while` loop, swaps to `N4->N3` and returns as `N3.next` is `None`
    - now, `p2` is `N2->N1->N4->N3` and you should just return it, but you continue...
  - second iteration: `p1, p2 = N1, N4` (because `head` is still `N1`)

    - swapped to `(N2,N4)->N1->N3` (both `N2` and `N4` having `N1` as `next`)
  - third iteration: `p1, p2 = N1, N3`

    - swapped to `(N2,N4,N3)->N1` (all of `N2,N4,N3` have `N1` as their `next`)
    - `p1=head=N1` finally has no `next`, so the loop stops, and you return `p2=N3`

Without the `while` loop is should already work correctly, returning the state after the first "iteration" of the (no longer existing) loop:

```
def swapPairs(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    if head is None or head.next is None:
        return head
    else:
        p1, p2 = head, head.next
        p1.next = self.swapPairs(p2.next)
        p2.next = p1
        return p2
```

Comment: Thank you so much!